# How to rewrite the username in addition to the email adress in postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

Following setup: Two servers, one with the (rails) web application and the other which actually sends the emails to the internet through postfix. Which means that any emails created by the web application get sent to the email server who processes them again.

Now, this means that emails got sent out with an email adress like "user@webserver.localdomain", which promptly led to the rejection of the emails by the target mail servers, due to the obviously missing mx record.

That one I fixed, though, with `smtp_generic_maps`, rewriting the sender adress to a valid one.

However, the sender name displayed in the email consists of two parts - and the first part seems to be automatically set by postfix by the username of the webserver creating the email. In this case "nginx".

So, how do I rewrite the displayed user name in addition to the email adress? Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?
To my defense: I did not setup this system myself, so I'm a bit of a beginner at all things sendmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, connect via TCP/IP to 127.0.0.1 port 25, and submit the mail using SMTP. that way you can set the from address to whatever you want. Currently you are submitting mail via the sendmail command, which is picking up the from address from user.

ps. sendmail != postfix

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to configure sendmail to accept connections on port 25 from localhost - because it doesn't at the moment :(